# Java custom shorthand expressions

Tags: java

Just to start this isn't a question I need an answer too. But I think it would be an interesting way of making code cleaner.

In some code I am writing Ive built a module for retrieving HTTP requests on a new thread and then returning the result to the main thread using a callback.

Code example:

```
public interface MyCallback {
    void Callback_done(String Data);
}
public void HTTP_process(String get_vars, List<NameValuePair> post_vars,MyCallback callback){
    Task = new GET_Task();
    Task.get_vars = get_vars;
    Task.post_vars = post_vars;
    Task.callback = callback;
    Task.execute();
}
public class GET_Task extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    public MyCallback callback;
    public String get_vars="";
    public List<NameValuePair> post_vars = null;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //displayProgressBar("Downloading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //CODE HERE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        callback.Callback_done(result);
    }
}
```

Then to use the above "library":

```
Globals.mData_Handler.HTTP_process("",null,new Data_Handler.MyCallback() {
                public void Callback_done(String Data) {//Callback code here
                }
           });
```

When I say shorthand I want to be able to type this instead:

```
Globals.mData_Handler.HTTP_process("",null,new ^{//Callback code here
                });
```

I know this is how objective C handles callbacks, is there a way to setup things like this in java? Using custom short hand expressions?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client?

Comment: how do you invoke callback on main thread :) the UI thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Java 8 and you get [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

```
Globals.mData_Handler.HTTP_process("",null, (String data) -> {
    //Callback code here
});
```

If you're only doing a one-liner you can even omit the braces:

```
Globals.mData_Handler.HTTP_process("",null, (String data) -> log.info(data));
```

Of course, the above can also be written using Java8 [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

```
Globals.mData_Handler.HTTP_process("",null, log::info);
```

Comment: additionally you can omit the parameter type: `(data)->...` and you can omit the parenthesis too: `data->...`

Comment: @theshadow124: The lambda wil be converted into a `Data_Handler.MyCallback` instance so there is no need to change the code in `Data_Handler`.

Comment: This solves my specific problem. But is there a way of implementing your own shorthand expressions or would it be counter productive?

Comment: You can't extend the Java language without adding a custom preprocessor, no.

Comment: @theshadow124 - invent your own language? :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, if I wanted to clean up my callback definition/function declaration how would I do this?

Comment: What do you mean? You only have to do `myFunction(MyCallback callback) {` - how much cleaner than that can you have it?

Comment: I mean in the definition currently i need to define public interface MyCallback then use MyCallback in the function definition. Using this method It would seem I could completely get rid of the public interface MyCallback

Comment: You could remove the definition of the `MyCallback` interface and use one of the [standard functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) if you find one that fits. A `Consumer<String>` might work.